# WCF server controlling client (windows forms)

Tags: wcf, client-server

I'm building an application, it's easy and what I want to do is the following. I want a brainless client and all the work should be done on the server. So I want a way to change windows forms in my server application and not on the client itself.

So when I have an application like blackjack the user presses hit then the hit function on the server get called, he will calculate everything, send the result back to the client and then the client updates it buttons and GUI (*like displaying cards, and so on*).

Now how do you do this in WCF? I know how to call remote function but I can't get the windows forms part to work (*can I add this in the contract, and how?*)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client should handle all of its own UI.  Your service shouldn't have anything to do with the UI.

Instead of having the service handle the UI, just have it send messages back to the client and let the client figure out which UI elements to show or not based on the messages.

So, when the server calculates some result, like BLACKJACK!, it'll send a message indicating that back to the client which will then show the proper UI elements.

Make sense?

Comment: Thanks alot, that was the answer I was looking for!